# JQuery mobile databox substract dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I try to calculte the age using jquery mobile datebox, but not since now, like in many descriptions. I've two dates: "born" "death" and the idea is to substract the first from the second.

```
 <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label>born</label>
        <input type="text" data-role="datebox" name="born" id="born" min="1808-04-01" max="1995-12-30" data-options='{"mode":"flipbox"}' />
      </div>
  <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label>died</label>
        <input type="text" data-role="datebox" name="death" id="death" min="1808-04-01" max="1995-12-30" data-options='{"mode":"flipbox"}' />
      </div>
```

But i've no idea how to handle this with jquery mobile or javascript.
It would be great to have this function in the cementery webbapp, on which i'm working now.
Any support would be gratefull

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here - https://jsfiddle.net/jdkahn90/vv6egb5s/

First I would suggest using a input type Date. Then you want to convert the input to a javascript Date object.

```
function subtract() {
var born = new Date(document.getElementById("born").value);
var death = new Date(document.getElementById("death").value);
```

There are 2 ways you can convert the difference to years. 
First is to just find the millisecond difference and divide by the number of milliseconds in a year. however, there is a slight caveat of leap years.

```
var diff = death - born;
var years = diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25);
```

Second is to find the year, month and day difference and just use if then statements to adjust. Up to you which sounds better.

```
var yearDiff = death.getFullYear() - born.getFullYear();
var monthDiff = death.getMonth() - born.getMonth();
if (monthDiff < 0) {
    yearDiff--;
} else if (monthDiff == 0) {
    var dayDiff = death.getDate() - born.getDate();
    if (dayDiff < 0) {
        yearDiff--;
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the date from a jQM DateBox widget you call `.datebox('getTheDate')` Once you have the 2 javascript date objects, you can subtract them to get the number of milliseconds between the 2 dates.

Then it is just a question of how you want to express the age? For just the years @jdkhan90's first option with `Math.floor()` to get the whole number of years:

```
var born = $("#born").datebox('getTheDate');
var death = $("#death").datebox('getTheDate');
var age = (death - born) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25);
alert("Age at death: " + Math.floor(age) + " years");
```

## **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/t39t42fy/)**

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys! Its working, but it was a litte bit tricky to handle the datebox types. type="date" is not working for me, so i use type="text" now and it is one mix from the samples of booth of you:

```
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>Age - Calculator</p>
      <br>

     <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label>Born:</label>
        <input type="text" data-role="datebox" name="born" id="born" min="1808-04-01" max="1995-12-30"  data-options='{"mode":"flipbox"}' />
      </div>
<div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label>Died</label>
        <input type="text" data-role="datebox" name="death" id="death" min="1808-04-01" max="1995-12-30"  data-options='{"mode":"flipbox"}' />
      </div>
      <button id="btnCalc">Calculate</button>
$(document).on("pagecreate","#pagethree", function(){ 
    $("#btnCalc").on("click", function(e){
    var born = $("#born").datebox('getTheDate');
    var death = $("#death").datebox('getTheDate');
    var diff = death - born;
    var age = diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25);
    alert("He/she was" + Math.floor(age) + " years old");  
  });
})
```